# How to make textbox inputs numbers with 2 decimal places and then check their sum?

Tags: vba, textbox

struggling with something in VBA and can't find a clear answer online. Quite new to this.  Basically, for the user form below (linked image due to my level), I would like to make all the textbox inputs be numbers (2 decimal places) and then when you click "Next" it checks that all the values sum to 100. If not, error message appears. I've tried lots of different ways of doing this and can't get it to work. I would like for all textbox inputs to be numbers (2dp), and then all the numbers to just add and then check this sum. For each textbox, I've done the following Sub Routine (variable name changes each time for name of textbox):

```
Private Sub BinQnt_AfterUpdate()
On Error Resume Next
Dim BinQnt As Single
BinQnt = Format(BinQnt, "percent")
End Sub
```

For the Next button I have done the following:

```
Private Sub MaterialsData_Next_Click()
'Check mix design = 100%.
'If = 100%, input data to database.

tot = BinQnt + FillQnt + FineQnt + CoarQnt + RAPQnt + CRQnt 'Names of each text box.

If tot = 100 Then
    'Code here for inserting values into database. Omitted to save space and confusion.

    'Go to next page.            
        BaseUserForm.MultiPage1.Value = 2

'If doesn't = 100%, then show error MsgBox
Else
    MsgBox "Error, please check mixture design sums to 100%. Currently at " & tot & "."
End If
```

[Screenshot of userform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8izQ.png)

Comment: What the heck does "2dp" mean?!?

Comment: 2 decimal places. Sorry.